# cloudcannon - pages configured as collection can only be edited as data

Tags: cloudcannon

I wanted to remove the "Add" button for the pages section, so I configured pages as collection in the _config.yml and it looks like this:

[image]

This did the work, and the "Add" button was gun. The problem is that now I can only access the data edit of all pages, and cant have access to the content or visual editor. Even if I try to add configuration to the _config.yml like this:

[image]

It doesn't work..
How can I remove the "Add" button, and still have the content and visual editor for the pages?

Answer (score 1):

The pages collection is a bit more involved, but this configuration should do what you want:

```
cloudcannon:
  collections:
    pages:
      _disable_add: true
      filter: strict
      output: true
      path: ''
```

Defining this collection under `cloudcannon` means it won't conflict with Jekyll's special collection called `pages`.

The other keys listed restore the default configuration you had for pages:

- `path` is where your pages are, most commonly in the root folder of your site. This is relative to your site source if you are using one.
- The `filter: strict` means you will only see files in this collection - since the `path` is the root folder you would otherwise see your other collections as subfolders.
- `output: true` says the source files in this collection have output files in the build - this restore access to the content and visual editor.